# Add multiple stops to Google navigation using Universal URL schemes

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, ios-universal-links

Is there a way to launch Google Maps app on iOS with multiple stops using [Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well we need to append `to:` parameter for each location. The url scheme will be as follows:

- from your current location

  `comgooglemaps://?daddr=Lat,Lon+to:Lat,Lon+to:Lat,Lon+to:...`
- if you have source location

  `comgooglemaps://?saddr=Lat,Lon&daddr=Lat,Lon+to:Lat,Lon+to:Lat,Lon+to:...`