# How to Launch google maps for ios with multiple waypoints of same address?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, ios-universal-links

I have an ios app which contains a list of selected address .
Now in that list last address is destination and remaining all address are waypoints. 
I have used google maps URL for launching google maps installed in device.

for waypoints i used solution given in [Add multiple stops to Google navigation using Universal URL schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363826/add-multiple-stops-to-google-navigation-using-universal-url-schemes)

It is working fine for different waypoints. But if i have same address multiple times in waypoints then it is not working.

It just opens google maps but not showing anything.

for example : `comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA+to:1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA+to:4+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA+to:10600+N+DE+Anza+Blvd,Cupertino,CA&directionsmode=driving`

here : destination is : **10600+N+DE+Anza+Blvd,Cupertino,CA**

and waypoints are = *1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA*  , *1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA* , *4+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA*

for your reference i am attaching screenshots :
expected result : [image: expected image]
actual result : [image]

please help me.

Comment: Google Maps URL won't work that way. You need to check and filter out the repeating places, then after filtering out form URL.

Answer (score 0):

you url have several issues :

- source param but empty address
- looks like you are using several time the same address

Try to use more meaningful addresses or points, like in :

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=18.519513,73.868315&daddr=18.518496,73.879259+to:18.520561,73.872435&directionsmode=driving
```

(This is tested and working)